# Is "midway through to X" acceptable?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Suppose I go a ballpark or some mall, and I forget to take the tickets or something like that along with me; I realize it on my way to the mall/ballpark.

Can I say:

> Midway through to the mall, I realized that I did not have the tickets and so I headed back.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here: which word to use, and which preposition(s) to use.

As for the word, normally, I'd probably say *halfway*, instead of *midway*, assuming I was roughly halfway there. If I wasn't around the midpoint of the trip, though, I'd be more likely to say, "Partway to the mall..." However, that's a stylistic choice; there's nothing wrong with the word *midway* (in fact, one could argue that, according to some dictionary definitions, *midway* is the better word, unless I was exactly halfway there).

Here are some definitions (from NOAD):

> **midway** (*adv.*) in or toward the middle of something : *Peter came to a halt midway down the street*
>
> **halfway** (*adv.*) at or to a point equidistant between two others : *he stopped halfway down the passage*
>
> **partway** (*adv.*) part of the way : *partway along the corridor he stopped*.

As for the preposition issue, I wouldn't say:

> Partway through to the mall...

Instead, a simple *to* will suffice:

> Partway to the mall....

Comment: As for your last, I'd disagree. *Partway from home to the mall*, but *partway through the mall, near the self-checkout* - one takes mall as endpoint, the other takes a point inside it!

Comment: @SF - Good point, you can use _to_ or _through_, depending on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not quite correct.  I can see two possible intentions:

1. I am going to the mall (I haven't got there yet) - when I realize I that I don't have the tickets
2. I am at the mall, but not at the specific location that needs tickets to get in (malls are fairly big) - when I realize I don't have the tickets.

For the first case, you need to remove the *through* from your sentence.  The construct 'midway through' gives the impression that you are already in the mall.  Additionally, *midway* will need to be replaced as it doesn't quite fit idiomatically. (Strictly speaking, I don't think it's incorrect to say 'midway to the mall ...', but it feels awkward to me.)     In this instance, I would change the sentence to:

> While on my way to the mall, I realized ...

or maybe:

> I was about halfway to the mall, when I realized ...

For the second case, the *to* in your example gives the impression that the subject (you) is not yet at the mall.  This is in the same sense as 'I am going to the mall'.  It is something I have not yet done.  Obviously, this isn't correct in the example, as you are already in the mall.

> Midway through the mall, I realized that I did not have the tickets
>   and so I headed back.

The issue is that **to** and **through** *in this instance* convey opposite impressions and one or the other needs to be removed from the sentence.

Comment: but I am not at the mall yet, I am on my way and that is when I realize that I don't have the tickets.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sentence is OK as is, by my understanding of its meaning.
You are moving, indicated by 'through". "midway" indicates somewhere in the middle of the mall, but not necessarily halfway.
Certainly there are other ways to say it, but as is I think its OK.